# VB.NET Crystal Report Viewer Locks other Forms

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports-2008

What will I do to allow other forms to perform while crystal report view is running?
Heres the code:

```
Public Sub printCurrentHistory()
    If dt.Columns.Count = 0 Then
        With dt
            .Columns.Add("update_time")
            .Columns.Add("sender")
            .Columns.Add("humidity")
            .Columns.Add("temperature")
            .Columns.Add("rain")
            .Columns.Add("wind_dir")
            .Columns.Add("wind_speed")
        End With
    End If
    For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In frmMain.dgvSearch.Rows

        dt.Rows.Add(dr.Cells("Updated").Value, dr.Cells("Sender").Value, dr.Cells("Humidity").Value, dr.Cells("Temperature").Value, dr.Cells("Rain").Value, dr.Cells("Wind_Direction").Value, dr.Cells("Wind_Speed").Value)
    Next

    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport1
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)

    frmPrint.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc
    frmPrint.ShowDialog()
    dt.Rows.Clear()
    dt.Clear()
    dt.Dispose()
    rptDoc.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Crystal Viewer Report Form:
[image]

Comment: what code are you using to show the form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx) and [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) is that `ShowDialog` is application Modal meaning it prevents anything else from happening until you close it. `Show` on the other hand throws up the `Form` and continues on its way. In looking at your code I would guess that your problem is that you are disposing of `rptDoc` and your datasource from underneath your `frmPrint`. You will need to change your frmPrint to be more autonomous. I would do something like.

```
frmPrint =  New ParentFormName(dt)  'The Form frmPrint is instantiated from
frmPrint.Show()
```

And then

```
Public Sub New( dt as DataTable)

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Dim rptDoc As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument      
    rptDoc = New CrystalReport1      
    rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt)      

    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc

End
```

And in your FormClosing event dispose of your Objects then.

This is untested code I am just trying to give you a few ideas.

---

Another option as I stated in my Comment is to add an Event to your print form and subscribe to it in Main Form like this.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim frm2 As Form2

    Private Sub CloseMyData()

        'Dispose of your Data here
        RemoveHandler frm2.myClosingEvent, AddressOf CloseMyData
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        frm2 = New Form2
        AddHandler frm2.myClosingEvent, AddressOf CloseMyData
        frm2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Form2
    Public Event myClosingEvent()

    Private Sub Form2_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        RaiseEvent myClosingEvent()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark but I don't know how to do it with my code.. I didn't  understand your code well. sorry im just new in VB. Is ParentFormName is a new class? And I can't convert frmPrint to New ParentFOrmName coz frmPrint is a windowsForm...

Comment: Is there any method or event that allows disposing of rptDoc or DataTable in form print when closing it??

Comment: @Jed You can try adding and event to your form print's closing method then subscribe to it in your main form using it to close your rptDoc and DataTable

Comment: @Jed To answer your questions. I do not know the name of the form that you used to create frmPrnt so I used a Generic name ParentFormName. You have a statement in your code where you state `frmPrnt = New formname`   or `Dim frmPrnt as New formname` what ever you used for formname that is what I meant by ParentFormName.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
  frmPrint.ShowDialog()
```

use

```
  frmPrint.Show()
```

Comment: Oh theres a problem. It gives **RUntime Error**. It says **- pure virtual function call (R6025)**. I think there's an issue in the use of `.Show`

Comment: Your using vb.net and you got that error what is the type of form ? Windows form ?